# Python: How to create a new dataframe from existing dataframe according to certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe called `df_new` and this is the current state:

```
       State_of_Discharge  Internal_Resistance
60                  0.308               -1.077
61                  0.308              307.745
182                 0.934                1.175
304                 1.560                0.392
305                 1.560              328.992
426                 2.186               -0.783
427                 2.186              329.384
548                 2.812                0.000
549                 2.813              323.705
670                 3.439                0.000
671                 3.439              320.180
```

I wish to take this dataframe and remove the values to exclude any values in `Internal_Resistance` that are near zero. The new data frame `df_sorted` shall look like this:

```
       State_of_Discharge  Internal_Resistance
61                  0.308              307.745
305                 1.560              328.992
427                 2.186              329.384
549                 2.813              323.705
671                 3.439              320.180
```

Comment: `near_zero` is a vague term. Can you tell the exact threshold of `Internal_Resistance` for which it should be omitted?

Comment: Let's say absolute value of '50'. So Anything within -50 to 50 shall be omitted.

Comment: @encer But the currently accepted answer only check for values greater than 50 but disregards negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `loc`:

```
df_sorted = df_new.loc[df_new['Internal_Resistance'] > 1.175]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) here and define `atol` parameter set to the whatever deviation range is accepted from 0, i.e say -5 to 5 are values near to 0 then `atol` is set to 5.

```
from functools import partial

isclose = partial(np.isclose,0,atol=5)
df[~isclose(df['Internal_Resistance'])]

     State_of_Discharge  Internal_Resistance
61                0.308              307.745
305               1.560              328.992
427               2.186              329.384
549               2.813              323.705
671               3.439              320.180
```

Note: This can be done without using `partial`, `df[~np.isclose(df['Internal_Resistance'],0,atol=5)]` gives same results but it's more verbose IMO.